# Error on IndexName of ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, delphi-10.2-tokyo

after the installation of RAD Studio 10.2 Tokio, and not in the previous version, the code give me an error.

When i assign a valid index string to the property IndexName of a ClientDataSet (not always but often, but i don't understand why) the code give me this error: exception message :

```
Access violation at address 4DB0D009 in module 'midas.dll'. Read of address 00000000.
```

These are the the steps before the error:

```
4db0d009 +000 midas.dll
0079489a +062 ... Datasnap.DBClient TCustomClientDataSet.SwitchToIndex
00794a72 +07e ... Datasnap.DBClient TCustomClientDataSet.SetIndex
0079516e +002 ... Datasnap.DBClient TCustomClientDataSet.SetIndexName
```

What could be the reasons be?

Comment: Refer to `CheckDbClient` in DSintf.Pas to see where the instance of Midas.Dll used by Delphi apps is registered in the Registry.  Then, try registering a different version and see if you still get the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i try and i get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

those reasons buried inside infamous midas.dll which is full of bugs. I'm afraid you have no choice other than trying different midas.dll version or fixing its bugs

Answer (score 1):

The problem is inside SwitchToIndex procedure of DataSnap.DBClient, i think; on the row:

```
Status := FDSCursor.UseIndexOrder(MarshaledAString(MetaDataFromUnicode(IndexName)));
```